# Select subarray from a numpy array on labels

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have processed an image with a skimage library's segmentation module. It produces a square numpy array with all segments labelled with unique number. Let's say we have a 400*400 image with let's say 500 segments labelled with 500 unique numbers.

I need to select 500 subarrays for each segment and save each as a separate image.

I could use a very brutal simple algorithm with a couple of for loops, but I strongly believe there's a simpler method using numpy masking methods. The problem is I cannot cope with it myself :-(

The code that generates the segments is very simple:

```
from skimage import future, graph, segmentation
import numpy as np

img_name = 'lion.jpg' 
img = io.imread(img_name)    

labels = segmentation.slic(img, compactness=10, n_segments=500)
```

As a result we have a 2D array labels.

My objective is to run a loop

```
for label in labels:
```

and cut subarrays for each label as a square with ones for pixels labelled and zeros for the remaining pixels.

Thanks,
Franek

Comment: What language and platform are you using? This documentation would help you formulate your question better: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/. Also, what have you tried thus far?

Comment: To me it's not really clear what your expected result will look like. What do you mean by "cut subarrays for each label as a square". Can you construct a simplified example (i.e. "mini-image") and explicitly show us your expected result?